# .BAT file to read contents of a .TXT file and assign to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file containing a text value only a 1 or 0 and wish to assign the value stored in this text file to a variable in a .BAT file. I have tried this to no avail:

```
set valuefromtextfile= <"C:\path\to\text\file\text.txt"
```

Then to print this on screen

```
echo|set /p T=%valuefromtextfile%
```

This just produces an empty line on screen when running this. Any ideas? Apologies, just new to .BAT files.

Comment: `set /p "var=" < file.txt` (reads the first line only!). To read more, your best choice is probably a `for /f` loop (see `for /?`)